# Given the following, how do I find the number of normalized floating-point numbers and why?

Tags: binary, floating-point

I'm trying to understand how floating point number arithmetic plays a role in computer science when using the binary system. I came across an excerpt from [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://web.cse.msu.edu/~cse320/Documents/FloatingPoint.pdf) which defines normalized numbers as unique floating-point numbers with the leading significand being non-zero. It goes on to say...

> When β
>   = 2, p  = 3, e min  = -1 and e max  = 2 there are 16 normalized floating-point numbers, as shown in Figure D-1.

Where **β** is the *base*, **p** is the *precision*, **e min** is the *minimum exponent*, and **e max** is the *maximum exponent*.

My attempt at understanding how he came to the conclusion of there being 16 normalized floating-point numbers was to multiply together the possible number of significands **β^p** and the possible number of exponents **e max - e min + 1**. My result was *32 possible normalized floating-point values*. I am unsure of how to get the correct result of *16 normalized floating-point values* as was declared in the paper above. I assumed negative floating-point values were excluded, however, I did not include them in my calculations.

This question is more geared toward mathematical formulae. But it will help me to better understand how floating-point arithmetic works in computer science.

I would like to know how to get the correct result of 16 normalized floating-point numbers and why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the first bit is always 1, with 3 bits for the mantissa you have only two bits to vary, yielding 4 different mantissa values. Combined with 4 different exponent values that's 16. I haven't looked at the paper though.

Comment: We've had differences before, but “I haven't looked at the paper” about WECSSKAFPA: +1

Answer (score 1):

> My attempt at understanding how he came to the conclusion of there being 16 normalized floating-point numbers was to multiply together the possible number of significands β^p and the possible number of exponents e max - e min + 1

This is correct except that the number of possible significands is not β<sup>p</sup> in binary with an implicit leading 1. In these conditions, the number of possible significands is β<sup>p-1</sup>, encoded over p-1 bits.

In other words, the missing values for the possible significands have already been taken advantage of when the encoding reserved, say, 52 bits to encode a precision of 53 binary digits.

Comment: Ah yes! The confusing issue of number systems. β^p-1 should be used for binary because the leading value cannot be zero for normalized floating-point numbers, and since there is no other number besides 1, the first value is fixed.

Comment: @WanderingIdiot It is possible the make the first digit explicit, in fact the 8087 made it so in order to simplify the circuitry that had to deal with extended-precision numbers, as documented in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#x86_Extended_Precision_Format